# Mongodb process keeps on getting killed by OOM Killer in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, memory-management, crash, out-of-memory

The mongodb process in my VPS keeps on getting killed randomly after few days of uptime. I'm running a Linode cloud server with 8GB memory and have a SAAS application deployed which uses mongodb as a multi tenant database.

This is the output of `dsmesg | grep -i kill` command
[image: oom killer log]

Any idea on how to optimize server configurations to prevent mongodb from crashing? I don't want to upgrade my memory as of now because mongodb would use (50% - 1GB) of system memory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your mongod process maybe fighting for memory with other process in this VPS and kernel decided preventively to kill it , what you can do is reducing the [cacheSizeGB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) from the default ( in your case 4GB ) to let say 2GB , the service may become slower but at least will not be killed. Afcourse it is recommended to increase the memory if your database is much more bigger then 8GB ...